# By what fractional part is exceeding?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

I was reading the following puzzle:

> Look here, George, said his cousin Reginald:  "by what fractional part
> does four-fourths exceed three-fourths?"
>
> "By one-fourth!" shouted everybody at once.
>
> "Try another one," George suggested.
>
> "With pleasure, when you have answered that one correctly," was
> Reginald’s reply.

According to the solution the correct answer is $\frac{1}3$ because $3$ of anything if increased by $\frac{1}3$ become $4$.

I don't really get it though. I can think of having a set of $N$ objects and somehow consider that each object is $\frac{1}N$ to the set so to add one more object you consider it as equivalent to adding $\frac{1}N$ but that seems a very weird way to state this.

Can someone please explain what this means?

Comment: "shouted everybody at once."  Who the heck is *everyone*?  I thought Reginald was only talking to George.

Comment: It depends and what "fractional part" means. The person telling the story (who doesn't seem to know how quotes mark work) seems to think "fractional part" means: by what fraction of $\frac 34$ is $1$ more than $\frac 34$.   If so $1$ is $\frac 14$ more than $\frac 34$ and $\frac 14$ is one-third of $\frac 34$ so $1$ exceeds $\frac 34$ but $\frac 13$ of three-fourths..  ...  But I have never heard of anyone referring to the fraction proportion of $a$ to $M$ as "the fractional part of $M$" and that makes zero sense to me... to most mathematicians "fractional part" has a very *different* meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount added is $\frac44-\frac34=\frac14$, so the **amount** by which $\frac44$ exceeds $\frac34$ is $\frac14$. However, the question does not ask for the amount of the excess: it asks what **fraction** of the original amount of $\frac34$ has been added to make the new amount of $\frac44$. Thus, what’s wanted is

$$\frac{\text{amount added}}{\text{original amount}}=\frac{\frac14}{\frac34}=\frac13\,.$$

Comment: To be fair "fractional part" is not a common of well defined term.

Comment: @fleablood: This usage used to be more common than it is now. The problem is from Henry Dudeney’s *Amusements in Mathematics*, which was published in 1917.

Comment: Yeah... I'm grouchy.

Comment: @fleablood: I’ve had days like that. :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: This explains it and makes real sense in the context of the original problem. But the expression used by the solution "because 3 of anything if increased by $\frac{1}3$ become 4" is still unclear to me. What exactly does it say? How could it be rephrased in a different way aligned with your answer?

Comment: @Jim: If you have $3$ of something, and you increase that to $4$, you’ve increased your holding by $1$. That increase if $\frac13$ of what you started with, so you’ve increased your holding by $\frac13$, i.e., by $33⅓\%$.

Comment: So basically the question is implicitly asking  "by what fractional part **of $\frac{1}3$** does four-fourths exceed three-fourths"? So I should have realized that the **of** part is missing and then think what that would be part of? Is that right?

Comment: @Jim: Yes: there’s an implicit assumption that we’re talking about a fractional part of the original amount. We do much the same thing when we say that price of something went up $10\%$: that’s $10\%$ of the original price.